# Match repository names with regex

Tags: regex, gitolite

Some of my repositories share a naming convention and thus have the same ending, e.g

```
tools2
subdirectory/tools2
subdirectory/etc/tools2
```

I want to match these repositories with a single regex (if possible) in my gitolite conf file.

```
@tools_repos = .*tools2
```

When I try to push this change, it gives me an error

> FATAL: bad expansion '.*tools'

If I understand correctly my pattern needs to be a subset of

```
$REPONAME_PATT        =  qr(^\@?[0-9a-zA-Z][-0-9a-zA-Z._\@/+]*$);
$REPOPATT_PATT        = qr(^\@?[[0-9a-zA-Z][-0-9a-zA-Z._\@/+\\^$|()[\]*?{},]*$);
```

Reading the [documentation](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#repo-regex-patterns) I came up with this regex

```
[a-zA-Z0-9].*tools2
```

but this solution does not match

```
tools2
```

Is there a simple way to match the repositories with a single regex?

Comment: +1 for the nice constructed question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If '`?`' is supported, you can try:

```
 [a-zA-Z0-9]?.*?tools2
 # or
 [a-zA-Z0-9].*?t?ools2 (suggested by HamZa)
```

Maybe the **non-greedy form** would allow for tools2 to be matched.

The [OP prakti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4069403/prakti) [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989527/match-repository-names-with-regex/25989763?noredirect=1#comment40700406_25989763) this seems to work:

```
 [a-zA-Z0-9]?.*tools2
```

Comment: I think the whole problem is that `[a-zA-Z0-9]` is preventing the match of `tools2`

Comment: Indeed, I'm just wondering if he wants to enforce a word character at the beginning. If that's the case we could get hacky and make `t?` optional as in `[a-zA-Z0-9].*t?ools2`. Guessing around... Edit: oh but that would also match `fools2` :P

Comment: @HamZa Indeed. I have suggested both in the answer. Let's see if the OP can tell us if any of those options works.

Comment: Using this regex gitolite created an empty repository named [a-zA-Z0-9].*?tools2

Comment: @prakti you mean with an empty name?

Comment: @VonC Sorry, gitolite actually did not create a repository.  The output of  `ssh git@dev info`confused me: `R W    [a-zA-Z0-9].*?tools2
 R W    gitolite-admin` But it did not match `tools2` by itself. Your second suggestion `[a-zA-Z0-9]?.*tools2` seems to work, although I thought gitolite would raise an error here just like using e.g. `.*tools`, because it would match invalid repository names such as `/tools2` or `:tools2` as well.

Comment: @prakti Ok, I have added in the answer the version which seems to work.

Comment: @VonC @HamZa Thanks for all your help, I will accept your answer. Can someone perhaps please clarify why `[a-zA-Z0-9]?.*tools2` works, but `.*tools2` raises an error? Both regexes would match 'bad' repository names it seems. (Sorry, had to delete my old comment because of a bad typo in the regex.)

Comment: @prakti not sure actually. It would be interesting to see, just for testing, if `[a-zA-Z0-9]?.*` works too (even though it would certainly match bed repos names)